# How to terminate an ncurses program with the `raw()` setting turned on?

Tags: c, ncurses

In order to save time, I'd like to know if there's a professional way to terminate an unresponsive ncurses program (from the terminal) with the `raw()` setting turned on. Here, <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> Won't help.

Example progam:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    raw();

    while(1)
    {
        printw("Yello\n");
    }

    refresh();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe ^C won't work? You just need a signal handler to capture `SIGINT` and do what you need done before termination.

Comment: @mah, But what if the program doesn't have that built in?

Comment: This is a programming q/a site, which pretty much expects you have the source to build your program and are asking about changing it, so if you don't have it built in, you build it in :)    If you're asking about a program you don't have source to build yourself, you probably have come to the wrong site (but you can kill the program by process id from a different terminal, and if you're on a *nix system and want to fix keyboard i/o on the terminal that had the killed process, in that terminal issue `stty sane` as a command (even if you cannot see what you type in it).

Comment: @mah, So there is no quicker and easier way to terminate the program, other than killing it from another terminal? That's what I wanted to know. TY for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you hit the `Control-C` (`C-c`) combination, the terminal parses it and then sends a signal (SIGINT) to whatever application is running in the foreground. `Control-C` has no special meaning to the operating system, only to the terminal.

When you call ncurses' `raw()` or `cbreak()` function, it essentially instructs the terminal to ignore these special characters and pass them on directly to whatever's running in the foreground, essentially instructing the terminal that the application "knows what it's doing".

So yes, you would have to "manually" (i.e. from another terminal) kill the running application:

```
ps aux | grep your_executable_name
kill the_pid
```

Yes, you can do this while in a TTY. And yes, you can jam your whole system if you lock all available TTYs (and don't have SSH access).